# ColdFusion don't see my IIS websites

Tags: iis, coldfusion, iis-6, coldfusion-11

I got 2 websites in my *IIS*.

When I'm trying to link ColdFusion and IIS, ColdFusion web server tool don't see my websites.
You can see it in the image.

My ColdFusion version is 11 Enterprise Edition, IIS version 6.1, Windows server 2008 rc2 operating system.

I'm working on Oracle Virtualbox.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Known [CF11 bug](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3761543). You need to install the Microsoft C++ 2008 x64 SP1 Redistributable (or x86 if you're running 32bit).

Comment: Just saw your using IIS 6.1 - the bug i referenced was with iis 7.5 IIS 6 is rather old, any reason you have not updated to 7.5?

Comment: Thanks this is just what i needed. But now i got a new error."You do not have permission to view this directory or page because of the access control list (ACL) configuration or encryption settings for this resource on the Web server." I looked at permissions twice it seeems allright. Any suggestions?

Comment: ACL's are network control goodness, speak to someone on your network team.

Answer (score 0):

The Visual C++ redistributable package is missing. Install [**Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86/x64)**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2092) and then try again.